# Can The Duration Of Illusory Reality Be Extended?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wizard, metamagic

As a related question to [this one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/75780/can-illusory-reality-bind-or-restrain-opponents/75782#75782), is there any way to extend the duration of Illusory Reality? My thoughts are either:

- Through re-casting it with a bonus action on the next round, or
- Extend it with an Extended Spells metamagic

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Re-using the class ability (not re-casting it — it's not a spell!) on the following round would work, in that doing so would replace the previous effect with a new one with a fresh 1-minute duration. This is because [same-name effects overlap without stacking](http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/DMG_Errata.pdf), with only the most powerful one actually giving its effect:

   > **Combining Game Effects.** [W]hen two or more game features have the same name, only the effects of one of them — the most potent one — apply while the durations of the effects overlap.

   Since they have equal potency it doesn't matter which is actually in effect; the point is that they can overlap just fine and when one expires the remaining one will continue the effect uninterrupted.
2. Since it's not a spell, metamagic can't be applied to it.

Comment: @Miniman I initially thought so based on the “When you cast…”, but it does almost immediately also say “You can do this on your turn as a bonus action **while the spell is ongoing**”. Personally I think that the intent was to give you the chance to do this *once* but leaving ‘when’ flexible, but I can't support that impression without getting into high-level grammar/semantics/pragmatics reasoning that tends to be foreign to the interpretive framework often called “rules-as-written”. At my table I'd rule it's once-only, though, yeah.

Comment: I don't know how, but I completely missed that. Not doing well this morning.

Comment: @Miniman I very nearly wrote a whole different answer saying "no no no," but with more words, because I missed it the first time too. It's not just you. :)

Comment: @Miniman Jeremy Crawford [clarified](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/618265562720808960) some time ago that you can make **only one object real per illusion spell** - though this leaves open to interpretation (to be read: nitpicking) if you can "remake" the same object multiple times

Answer (score 4):

Illusory Reality is a spell feature granted by the school of illusion arcane tradition, so it cannot be affected by metamagic.
It also cannot be "recast" - at least not in the way you mean it.

That being said, let's start from the relevant part of the feature description:

> When you cast an illusion spell of 1st level or higher, you can choose one inanimate, nonmagical object that is part of the illusion and make that object real.
>   You can do this on your turn as a bonus action while the spell is ongoing.

Additionally, we know that you can make **only one object real per illusion spell** thanks to [this](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/622179998233800708) and [this](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/618265562720808960) clarification by Jeremy Crawford:

> The feature is meant to be read in its entirety, which talks about one object.
>   The bonus-action sentence doesn't undo that.
>
> Illusory Reality is intended to make one illusory object real per illusion spell.

So now that the technicalities are out of the way, let's see if there's a way to prolong Illusory Reality:

- there is nothing in the RAW or in any erattas published by Crawford that prevents you from reusing Illusory Reality on the same object as part of the same illusion spell, so that should work according to the rules for combining magical effects

  > The effects of different spells add together while the durations of those spells overlap.
  >   The effects of the same spell cast multiple times don't combine, however.
  >   Instead, the most potent effect—such as the highest bonus—from those castings applies while their durations overlap.
- another option would be to simply cast another illusion spell recreating the same illusion and using the Illusory Reality feature on the new spell. However, this is not very practical, as illusion spells that could benefit from the Illusory Reality feature either require concentration - interrupting the previous illusion - or have a casting time longer than one action.

As a final note, there is nothing in the feature description that says you can end the effect of Illusory Reality, so once an object is made real it stays for the full 1 minute duration.
It may be possible to remove the object by interrupting or dispelling the spell, depending on how "real" the object is.

> The object remains real for 1 minute.