# Can Illusory Reality be reused on the same object that is part of the same spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wizard, illusion

Based on [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/75784/can-the-duration-of-illusory-reality-be-extended).

> **Illusory reality** (PHB p. 118)
>
> When you cast an illusion spell of 1st level or higher, you can choose one inanimate, nonmagical object that is part of the illusion and make that object real. You can do this on your turn as a bonus action while the spell is ongoing.

Jeremy Crawford clarified however that you can only make one object real per illusion spell ([here](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/622179998233800708) and [here](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/618265562720808960)).

> The feature is meant to be read in its entirety, which talks about one object.
> The bonus-action sentence doesn't undo that.
>
> Illusory Reality is intended to make one illusory object real per illusion spell.

Is the intent that the **Illusory reality** feature can be used only once per spell, or is it allowed to be used multiple times per spell, but only for one (the same) object, effectively allowing you to refresh the duration on that object?

---

As an example, can you make real an object, and as the 1 minute duration of illusory reality expires, refresh the feature on the same object? Can you do this while the first use of **Illusory reality** has not expired yet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can The Duration Of Illusory Reality Be Extended?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/75784/can-the-duration-of-illusory-reality-be-extended)

Comment: @GreySage the answers to that question, which I also linked, simply states that it's possible, without explaining why or going into the implications

Comment: How exactly would you make one illusory object real, multiple times?

Comment: Your question, as I read it, is "Can you do this?". That question already answers it, "Yes you can." If you want to ask why or something else, please edit the question to reflect that, since right now it only asks if you can.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pg 118 PHB

> **Illusory Reality**
>   By 14th level you have learned the secret... choose **one** inanimate, nonmagical object that is part of the illusion and make that object real.  **You can do this on your turn as a bonus action while the spell is ongoing**.  The object remains real for **one minute**.

RAW there's nothing against recasting Illusory Reality on the same object, if you did it would simply apply the Combining Magical Effects (Pg 205 PHB) rule which states:

> **Combining Magical Effects**
>   The effects of different spells add together while the durations of those spells overlap.  The effects of the same spell cast multiple times don't combine, however.  Instead, the most potent effect -- such as the highest bonus -- from those castings applies while their durations overlap.

TL;DR:
According to RAW, you can reapply this as a bonus action, and the duration would be extended, though the object wouldn't become more real.

Answer (score -1):

It was just published today on the June [SageAdvice](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/rules-answers-june-2016)

> Does the 14th-level Illusionist ability let you make something real
>   every round, or just once? Illusory Reality is intended to make ***one
>   illusory object real per illusion spell.***

I realize this technically says *intended* but this means it was intended by the writers.

To be honest doing more than one per casting of a spell could definitely be abused. Illusions can be very unfair given careful thought and preparation... even without this ability. I have seen whole parties die to a single well placed illusion.

Comment: That link is already quoted in the question, so this isn't adding anything new.

Answer (score -1):

There is no reason why you can't cast two illusions and thus get two objects, assuming they are both going on at the same time. One per spell means for each spell, you get one.

Or, because your question isn't exactly clear in what it's asking: yeah, just cast another illusion, and dispel your previous one. Have this new spell include that object, and then make it real.

Comment: That is indeed true. However, that's not what I'm asking. The question is about making **one** object, that is part of **one** spell, real twice (after the first minute of illusory reality expires)

Comment: It's already real. How can you make it real twice? Once it expires, it expires, and you need to make a new illusion to make it a copy of the object, and make it real.

Comment: That is a valid opinion, and should be included in the answer. Note though that the linked question seems to imply that doing this is possible (without providing any explanation - which is actually what I'm looking for).